# Why can't download video even I removed nodownload from controlsList

Tags: javascript, video

It is basically the title.
Although `video.controlsList.remove('nodownload')` removes the nodownload ability, meaning that I should be able to download the video. However, when I run `video.controlsList.support('nodownload')`in the console, it still returns `true`.It is really strange.

Comment: **(1)** What browser are you testing on? In Chrome the `<video>` tag's download option is auto-available (click on the 3 dots) **(2)** How can this [example code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) be adjusted to recreate your situation? Paste the edited code [into your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71919320/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`video.controlsList.support()` is used to check if a particular functionality is supported by that browser. When you use it you are basically asking the browser "Hey i want to use this feature. do you support it?" It doesn't tell the value of that attribute in the video tag.